# Grails 3 custom web.xml and weblogic.xml

Tags: tomcat, grails, gradle, weblogic, grails-3.0

[Grails 2 documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/guide/deployment.html) says that is it possible, but Grails 3 documentation didn't says nothing about.

How can I add a custom web.xml and weblogic.xml to a Grails 3 application war?

Comment: Because Grails 3 is a rewrite of Grails on top of Spring Boot, I would check to see how Spring Boot would allow you to add those xml files.

Comment: I've found the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) but I can't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3.x does not use web.xml. Customizations must be done in Spring. New servlets and filters can be registered as Spring beans or with ServletRegistrationBean and FilterRegistrationBean respectively.

Documentation for configuring Spring Beans in Grails: 
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/spring.html

Information gathered from http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#upgradingApps

**The article does mention, poorly worded, "although it is still possible to have on in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"**

Try creating a **web.xml** file located in **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/** and see if this solves your issue.

In previous version of grails you could run:

```
grails install-templates
```

This would generate the web.xml grails uses to build your application.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this from the JavaOne talk that Graeme Rocher gave on October 24, 2015. It looks like `web.xml` is no longer supported.

[Here is the the video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/grails-3-x), it's about one hour into the presentation. (Slides are available for download on the site). Here are some screenshots from the presentation:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---